# How to use for loop and if in a one line list in python

Tags: python, list

```
dd = 0
[dd+=1 if 'A' in sequence for sequence in ss]
```

This gives syntax error. Any ideas how to fix the code?

Comment: The `if` is interpreted as a ternary operator.

Comment: [dd+=1 if 'A' in sequence for sequence in ss]
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (on the = sign)

Comment: See [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

Comment: in most cases it would be more pythonic to this on seperate lines

Comment: Don't strive to have code fit on one line; strive for it to be readable.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it can be readable and in one line.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's just gravy though if you can make it readable on one line.

Comment: if you bench the execution times you'll see it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
dd = 0
for sequence in ss:
    if 'A' in sequence :
        dd+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) to do counts like this.

```
sum('A' in sequence for sequence in ss)
```

Because `True` equals one and `False` equals zero, this return a count of the number of times the given condition is true.